# clear screen shortcut (ctrl-L) stop working in zsh

Tags: zsh, iterm2

zsh 5.8 (arm-apple-darwin20.2.0)

All shortcuts works except `ctrl-L`, but type command `clear` works. What could be the reason?

Comment: Some things to check: a) Does `bindkey` list `"^L" clear-screen`? b) Is there a shortcut for `^L` in the macOS System Preferences -> Keyboard? c) Has some hotkey been set in the `iterm2` app preferences? d) Does the same thing happen in Terminal?